# live log from docker container

Tags: docker, logging, live

How to have live log from a docker container?

After many sleepless nights and many many internet searches an answer finely comes to me in a dream I would say - Hey! just detach the dumb container!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way if you have the container running and sending logs to stdout, is to use `docker attach` , here is an example of running a container and attaching to it to see the output

```
$ docker run -d --name topdemo ubuntu /usr/bin/top -b

$ docker attach topdemo
```

basically this is the syntax of the command `docker attach [OPTIONS] <CONTAINER>`

Answer (score 0):

After searching quite a lot(!),
I am using it like this:

```sh
NUM=`docker run -d --user 1013830000 -p 4567:4567 container_test:v1`
docker logs -f $NUM
docker stop $NUM
```

Comment: This does answer the question; can you explain why, and remove the unnecessary parts of the code fragment?